# Proper check to ensure scrollbars

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I've got a pop up window from Javascript. However, this window has dynamically generated content - a person could add dozens of entries, which would fill the box, but because the box is frequently generated with little content in it, it does not naturally have a scrollbar.

How would I add a test in Javascript to make sure that everytime this script runs, a test to see if a scrollbar should be implemented is run, and then how would I implement the scrollbar?

Comment: Why do you need JavaScript? Won’t `overflow: auto` or `overflow-y: scroll` do the job?

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open ("http://www.javascript-coder.com", "mywindow","scrollbars=1");
```

Or, you may be able to take this into the hands of CSS:

In the popup:

```
body {overflow-y:auto !important};
```